# Updating AngularJS ng-repeat table due to dynamic JSON changes

Tags: angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat

i want to display the last activity status of each animal, whereas activity stati and animals may change over time.

First I get this JSON:

```
$scope.JSON = [
{"Animal" : "Horse", "Status" : "awake", "LastUpdate" : { "$date" : 1473248184519 }},
{"Animal" : "Rabbit", "Status" : "awake", "LastUpdate" : { "$date" : 1473248194240  }},
{"Animal" : "Rabbit", "Status" : "eating", "LastUpdate" : { "$date" : 1473249639255  }},
{"Animal" : "Horse", "Status" : "eating", "LastUpdate" : { "$date" : 1473249652549  }},
{"Animal" : "Horse", "Status" : "sleeping", "LastUpdate" : { "$date" : 1473249656338  }}
]
```

If an animal is doing something new, the JSON changes automatically, f.e. the rabbit is now sleeping as well as if a new animal appears, f.e. a cow:

```
$scope.JSON = [
{"Animal" : "Horse", "Status" : "awake", "LastUpdate" : { "$date" : 1473248184519 }},
{"Animal" : "Rabbit", "Status" : "awake", "LastUpdate" : { "$date" : 1473248194240  }},
{"Animal" : "Rabbit", "Status" : "eating", "LastUpdate" : { "$date" : 1473249639255  }},
{"Animal" : "Horse", "Status" : "eating", "LastUpdate" : { "$date" : 1473249652549  }},
{"Animal" : "Horse", "Status" : "sleeping", "LastUpdate" : { "$date" : 1473249656338  }},
{"Animal" : "Rabbit", "Status" : "sleeping", "LastUpdate" : { "$date" : 1473249659505  }},
{"Animal" : "Cow", "Status" : "awake", "LastUpdate" : { "$date" : 1473249659505  }};
]
```

This JSON expands over time, therefore I want to display only the last value of the different animals in a table like this:

**Animals Table Example:**
[image: Animals Table Example]

The **main problem** is, that new animals are added over time into the jSON and should automatically detected and added into the table.

I thought of two Solutions:

**1, ng-repeat + filter + limitTo**

For this attempt please have a look at this Plunker
https://plnkr.co/edit/ftea6vd1qaPZaXGusZAN

This provides me nearly everything except the automatical detection of new animals, **any suggestions**?

**2, creating subset JSONs for each animal**

I would create a new JSON subset containing only one animal and ng-repeating over this new JSON (with lastitem). By looping over all animals (how to get all animals? maybe as a foreach list?) I may get each last status of each animal?

**Is this better, or even possible?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a method to provide the data to the ng-repeat instead of directly passing the JSON `ng-repeat="roll in filtering(JSON)`

And on that function would create something like:

```
function filtering(animals){
    var temp = [].concat(animals);
    var animalsExisting = []; // To keep track of animals already added
    return temp.reverse().filter(function(animal){
      var notAdded = animalsExisting.indexOf(animal.Animal) === -1;
      if(notAdded) animalsExisting.push(animal.Animal);
      return notAdded;
    });
}
```

So would reverse the array so it's start from the last added and filter them just getting the last one added (since it's reversed).

Hope this helps

Comment: I tried it in many ways, but i still have Problems, can you edit my plunker maybe? I think my main Problem is the variety of animal, Animal and animals variables.

Comment: @Martin, check if this might work, made 1 change. https://plnkr.co/edit/OQVjB47bpS9fKubO2lum